# how to customize the surfaceview camera and to pass the captured image to another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk

I have Created Customized Camera with Surfaceview and camera is working , but the captured image is not passing to an another activity.  how can i do this? Any one help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to capture image from surfaceview of customized camera and to show that image in next Activity in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912075/how-to-capture-image-from-surfaceview-of-customized-camera-and-to-show-that-imag)

Answer (score 0):

You must be saving that captured file on some location in Camera activity. Pass that fully qualified image path of that file as an `Intent` to another activity.
And now use this path to open the image in another activity.
In this way, you haven't passed the image directly to another activity but by passing image path, you can get the captured image in another file.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CameraCapture.this, SelectService.class);
i.putExtra("filepath", "/mnt/sdcard/projectname_temp/myPicName.jpg");
startActivity(i);
```